# find markdown files who contains a string date YYYY-MM-DD and sort them by the most recent

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to `find` markdown files who contains (`grep`) a string date `YYYY-MM-DD` and `sort` them by the most recent :

```
for markdown in $(find content/note/ -type f \( -name "*.md" ! -name "index.md" \) -exec cat {} \; | grep -E '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}' | sort -rn); do
  echo $markdown
done
```

But unfortunately `$markdown` do not return the file name, but the string from the `grep` and the `sort` commands ...

So what can i do for sort and then return the file name in descending order ?

Answer (score 1):

First problem: you say "certain files," yet you are searching only files that end with .md but do not match index.md.  Is that what you meant by "certain files" in this context?

Second, thanks for the tip (grep), but I don't see you grepping anything.

How about the following:

**DIGIT="[0-9]"

    DATE_PATT="$DIGIT$DIGIT$DIGIT$DIGIT-$DIGIT$DIGIT-$DIGIT$DIGIT"

    MATCHING_FILES=$(   find . -name "*.md" \& ! -name index.md |

        xargs grep -c "$DATE_PATT" |

        grep -v ":0$" |

        sed "s/:[0-9]*$//"

       )**

Note that "grep -c" prints only one line per file, that is, how many matches are within the file, and the subsequent "grep -v" discards those output lines for which the count is zero, while the "sed" strips off the colon and count altogether, and the resultant list of space-separated filenames is assigned to the shell variable $MATCHING_FILES.

Note also that the $DATE_PATT" must be quoted because, otherwise, the shell will detect the '[' and try to expand to find matching filenames in the current directory.  That's not at all what we want.  Same thing for the quoted '&' (I used a backslash to maximize ugliness).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes certain files mean "files that end with .md but do not match index.md".

Comment: And if you scroll horizontally in my block of code you can see `grep -E '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}'` ... Do you mean it's doing nothing?